# Unable to correctly get order of permutation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

There is a [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFjBN.png) from the book Algebra Interactive, by Arjeh Cohen, that states in Ex. 5.1.10 that the order of permutation $[2\,\,1\,\,3]$ is $2$.

The book states on the same page the defn. of 'Order' of a permutation as:
 Order of a Permutation: The order of a permutation $g$ is the smallest positive
integer $m$ such that $g^m = e$.

On trying out: $[2\,\,1\,\,3]\,\,[2\,\,1\,\,3]$, get the mappings from right to left

$$2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 3$$
$$1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2$$
$$3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1$$

However, on getting the mapping one more time, i.e. $m=3$, get
$$[2\,\,1\,\,3]\,\,[2\,\,1\,\,3]\,\,[2\,\,1\,\,3]:$$

$$2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2$$
$$1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1$$
$$3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 3$$

So, is the book wrong in taking order as $2$.

Comment: Yeah, the book is wrong. The order of $(213)$ is $3$.

Comment: I think this is a notation confusion. You are reading $[2 1 3]$ as cycle notation $(213)$, whereas here it is list notation. It means $[1 2 3]$ maps to $[2 1 3]$ so only $1$ and $2$ are swapped, while $3$ stays in place.

Comment: You are misreading the text.  They specify that, here at least, they are writing elements of $S_3$ in what they call "list notation".  That is, they are writing down the entire permutation...so this is just the transposition of the first two elements.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, & Jaap Scherphuis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As already pointed out in comments, the list notation is being used here, where $[2\ 1\ 3]$ refers to the permutation that maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $1$ and $3$ to itself. Thus, this is indeed a transposition of order $2$.